# Unable to create aac/mp3 cbr 256k using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04, aac

I am using following commands to make aac/mp3 files with 256kbps bitrate and constant bitrate mode.

For aac:

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -b:a 256k -y test.aac
```

For mp3:

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -b:a 256k -y test.mp3
```

I need to make an aac file in CBR mode from a wav file. As per the documentation available at https://ffmpeg.org, CBR should be made using above mentioned commands but it is always making VBR.

I need help to see if I am doing something wrong, or there are some other steps to be followed. I have tested with ffmpeg versions 2.8 and 3.2.

Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: I *think* that the `-b` option behavior depends on the codec? i.e. for libfdk_aac, you'd specify bits, for Lame, kilobits etc.

Comment: @Yorik, Lame within ffmpeg also takes bits/s. The standalone tool may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native AAC encoder doesn't do CBR. It does ABR but can drift. `libfdk_aac` can do CBR.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Can u please guide me how can I achieve this, I followed the documentation but it didn't work

Comment: You need a build with lbfdk_aac compiled. What command did you use?

Comment: I have already done that, command used is ffmpeg -i test.wav -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 256k -y test.aac

Comment: How are you checking the output?

Comment: using mpck and mediainfo command

Comment: That's a raw bitstream. Save to `.m4a` and check

Comment: Thank @Mulvya for you help, mpck still shows VBR when making m4a

Comment: That's an issue with mpck.

Comment: Hi Mulvya, Thank you for helping me out, it was creating the right file but mpck was showing it wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It should be listed on the doc page that the native AAC encoder does not do CBR!